# If user enters number value - change ingredients based on that number?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I have an upcoming project where the client wants a way of entering a number into the website for it then to change the contents of something - for example: -

How many blocks of cheese do you have? (1)

Then you'll need;
100g of Tomato Sauce
200g of Pizza Dough
50g Fresh Tomato

-or-

How many blocks of cheese do you have? (2)

Then you'll need;
200g of Tomato Sauce
400g of Pizza Dough
100g Fresh Tomato

So it'll work out based on the number entered which can be anywhere from 1 to 9,999 how many of something else someone will need?

We aim to be developing in Wordpress so any links to plugins which may do this would be a huge help!

Hope this makes sense!

Many thanks!!

Comment: Hi Den, welcome to SO. You may find the SO tour page a helpful read https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: That's pretty basic JavaScript... And also your question is not being well received because: 1) asking for recommendations is off-topic; 2) outlining a list of requirements and asking "what's the code for that" is also off-topic. [so] works best when you have a specific programming issue (concept or code) that you need help with.

Comment: Added an answer for you, hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this way with `onchange` event of your number input and do some calculation to set you text as output. Hope this helps :)

```js
function updateInput(e) {
 // console.log(e);
  var val1 = e * 100;
  var val2 = e * 200;
  var val3 = e * 50;
  var msg = document.getElementById("msg");
  msg.innerHTML = `<font size="5">${val1} g of Tomato Sauce ${val2} g of Pizza Dough ${val3} g Fresh Tomato</font>`;
  ;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  How many blocks of cheese do you have? ( (between 1 and 9999): <input id="cheese_block" type="number" name="quantity" min="1" max="9999" onchange="updateInput(this.value)">
  <div id="msg"></div>
</body>

</html>
```